# How can I have a UI TableView start off screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I am trying to have a UITableView slide in from the left after a button is pushed. The table view should not be visible upon entering the main view. I also want the table view to occupy only a portion of the screenspace, not the entire screen, or else I would try making a separate view.

I have tried creating an IBOutlet to the tableview and shifting the position in viewWillAppear() using:

```
optionsTableView.center.x -= view.bounds.width
```

This didn't work, I think because of the constraint system?

Next I tried having the leading and trailing space constraints as placeholders, and in the viewDidLoad() block adding:

```
//Replace placeholder constraint with a constraint of less than or equal to 0
let leadingSpaceConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: optionsTableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.LessThanOrEqual, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
optionsTableView.addConstraint(leadingSpaceConstraint)

//Add Trailing space constraint
let trailingSpaceConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: optionsTableView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing,relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
optionsTableView.addConstraint(trailingSpaceConstraint)
```

However, this cause an error on loading the view

```
2015-08-28 09:00:58.638 ShotMaker[25585:1566797] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb033c48c30 H:|-(<=0)-[UITableView:0x7fb03506e800]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fb033c56ca0 )>
When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
2015-08-28 09:00:58.639 ShotMaker[25585:1566797] View hierarchy unprepared for constraint.
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, so any help would be appreciated. Or if you know of a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do I'd love to hear about it. (Container view? Implement the whole thing programmatically? Clever constraint manipulation?) 
Also, if you know why my first attempt at moving the center of the view didn't work that would also be useful information.

Finally, I haven't yet gotten to trying to animate the slide in from the left, as I've been hung up just by starting it off screen, but feel free to provide an idea of how to do this, as I really haven't a clue.

Thanks

P.S. This is my first question on stack exchange, so if I've made any formatting mistakes or if I could provide more information to be more helpful, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions.

You can set it off screen in Interface Builder, link the left/leading constraint to your view controller and update it's constant to shift the table view into place.

You can easily animate the table view in after changing the constant by using setNeedsLayout in an animation block :-)

You can also update the frame of the table view in viewDidLayoutSubviews, the frame of the table view is still being constructed inside loadView and viewDidLoad when using constraints in Interface Builder.